# Undefined method 'title' for nil:NilClass post.title

Tags: ruby-on-rails, undefined

I am creating a website with ruby on rails and want to add a post section.
I've looked StackOverflow up for solutions, but I couldn't get one for my needs.

show.html.erb

```
    <!-- Post Content Column -->
<div class="col-lg-8">
  <!-- Title -->
  <h1 class="mt-4"><%= @post.title %> </h1>
  <!-- Author -->
  <p class="lead">
    by
    <a href="#">Start Bootstrap</a>
```

---

posts_controller.rb

```
class PostController < ApplicationController

def index
    @posts = Post.all.order('created_at DESC')
end

def create
    @post = Post.new(params[:post].permit(:title, :text))

    if @post.save
        redirect_to @post
    else
        render 'new'
    end
end

def show
    @posts = Post.find(params[:id])
    @posts = Post.order("created_at DESC").limit(4).offset(1)
end

def edit
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
end

def update
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])

    if @post.update(params[:post].permit(:title, :text))
        redirect_to @post
    else
        render 'edit'
    end
end

def destroy
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    @post.destroy

    redirect_to posts_path
end


private
def post_params
    params.require(:post).permit(:title, :body)
end
```

I am new to rails and I don't really know how to fix this...

hope you guys can help me with this.

Thanks in advance for help and interest!

Comment: Change for use the private method post_params
  `@post = Post.new(post_params)`

 `if @post.update(post_params)`

And in your private method post_params, put the correct attributes, there you put :title, :body and in the method update and create you put :title, :text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `show.html.erb` file you use `@post` variable, but it is not defined in your `show` controller. This is the reason why you have error `Undefined method 'title' for nil:NilClass post.title`.

Instead you have `@posts` variable. By convention you should name this variable in singular form for show action.

Answer (score 1):

Your show action declare @posts with an s, the show view use @post without s.

Comment: yeah i figured that out already, but this won't solve my problem.. it still says undefined method 'title' for nil:NilClass

Comment: post the complete error message from the server console and update the code.

Comment: NoMethodError - undefined method `title' for nil:NilClass:
  app/views/website/quotes.html.erb:15:in `_app_views_website_quotes_html_erb___1963318634219542437_70100195574940'

I hope you mean this..

Comment: no, I mean the whole error message. Put it in the question, and update your code to match the last version.